# PHP: Instantiate Class using variable - $new = new $_GET['class_name'];

Tags: php, get, laravel-5

I need to instantiate a class in PHP. I don't know what that class should be until I grab a `$_GET['class_name']`.

I want to do this:

```
$new_id = \App\Identification\ . $_GET['class_name']::find(1);
```

Instead I have to do:

```
if($_GET['class_name'] == 'Student'){
      $new_id = \App\Identification\Student::find(1);
}
```

I would really love any help!

Comment: Then what you will do if `$_GET['class_name']` is not set or something that is not in your \App\Identification\?

Comment: @BeingSunny I have validation that will make sure the GET conforms to what I need and is valid before sending it.

Comment: Then what is the problem, you first choice isn't working ? it should work but with `$new_id =\App\Identification\ . $_GET['class_name'].::find(1);`

Comment: @BeingSunny What you have listed doesn't work. However, through your comments I was able to reason my way through it. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: @ Nathan Lochala did you see my answer?

Comment: I think you should review your design if you're using Laravel and still need $_GET

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this way

```
$classNamespace = "\App\Identification\";
$class=$_GET['class_name'];
$path=$classNamespace. $class;
$new_id = $path::find(1);
```

Comment: Yep, that's what I figured out as well. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @NathanLochala, sorry for little late, i was busy with other task, best of luck

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here was my problem:

I was trying to concatenate the namespace with the variable my $_GET was returning.

Example:

```
$new_id = \App\Identification\ . $_GET['class_name']::find(1);
```

That won't work.
This will:

```
$full_path = '\App\Identification\' . $_GET['class_name'];
$new_id = $full_path::find(1);
```